# check if is the hour within a range

Tags: php

I need to check if is the "`$current`" hour in range start / end.

```
$range_start = "18:00:00";
$range_end = "20:00:00";

$current = "17:59:59"; //false = not in range 18:00:00 - 20:00:00
$current = "19:00:00"; //true = in range 18:00:00 - 20:00:00
```

Help, Thank you

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `strtotime()` to convert them to `timestamp` and compare them.

```
if(strtotime($current) >= strtotime($range_start) 
   && strtotime($current) <= strtotime($range_end)) { ... }
```